# mysql query GROUP BY trimed data column

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm working with MYSQL, and have a problem with group by column that data has to be trimed first.
here is my table:

| src | dst |
| --- | --- |
| source one | some_character1/dst_one-random_value1 |
| source one | some_character1/dst_one-random_value2 |
| source one | some_character2/dst_two-random_value3 |
| source two | some_character4/dst_two-random_value1 |
| source two | some_character4/dst_three-random_value2 |
| source two | some_character2/dst_three-random_value7 |

i want to group by this table into like this :

| dst_group_by |
| --- |
| dst_one |
| dst_two |
| dst_three |

the dst value has 3 section.

The first section is seperated by '/', and the last section is seperated by '-'.

First section and last section character length is random, and i can determined it.
I only want to group by the middle section.

Is there any effective query to do that ?

Thanks before.

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: 'and i can determined it' - If you can what's your problem and what have you tried?

Comment: Use nested SUBSTRING_INDEX(). Or REGEXP_SUBSTRING().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get the between value you want to `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a.src, a.dst_group_by
FROM (SELECT src, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dst, '/', -1), '-', 1) AS dst_group_by
      FROM sample) a
GROUP BY a.src, a.dst_group_by
```

**Result:**

```
| src        | dst_group_by  |
|------------|---------------|
| source one | dst_one       |
| source one | dst_two       |
| source two | dst_two       |
| source two | dst_three     |
```

Or if you want to return the `DISTINCT` values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dst, '/', -1), '-', 1) AS dst_group_by
FROM sample
```

**Result:**

```
| dst_group_by  |
|---------------|
| dst_one       |
| dst_two       |
| dst_three     |
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2s5Ak06_).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has substring function, you can define like that

```
select src,substring(dst,start_position,substring_length) 
group by substring(dst,start_position,substring_length)
```

I don't know if the position is indexed by 0 or by 1 but the idea is like:

```
select src, substring(dst,16,6) 
from table_name 
group by substring(dst,16,6)
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Take a moment to read up on [formatting your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)